# What does 'Baked-in' mean?

Tags: terminology

I've come across the phrase multiple times the past month or so, usually when talking about functionality. Is this any different than saying 'built-in', or carry with it any specific connotations?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about terminology, not programming.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/baked+in+to):

> a. (Computers) to incorporate (a feature) as part of a
>   system or piece of software or hardware while it is still in
>   development: *The location-tracking service is baked in the new app.
>   Security features come baked into the operating system.*
>   b. To include
>   as an inseparable or permanent part: *Baked into the price of the
>   product is the cost of advertising.*

Answer (score 2):

Your assumptions are correct. It pretty much means that you don't have to do anything special to install this functionality. It's built in. Already there.

Other variants are:

- Rolled in
- Built in
- Native

Comment: "You get it for free."

Comment: In my experience 'baked in' has slightly more negative connotation when compared to 'built in'.  If something is built in then you get it for free, but if something is baked in then not only do you get it for free, but it actually might be difficult to take it out or to disable that feature. It has been included `as an inseparable or permanent part`.